# How to set Images in recycler-view and group it by date as shown in image in android (Java)?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I am looking for sorting of the images and set it in recycler-view. The sorting will be in date format and in decreasing order as shown in the image. Help me out.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: look into RecyclerView with multiple viewTypes, and gridLayoutManager

Comment: you need to use the section recyclerview for this requirement. check this link it will cover your needs. https://www.androhub.com/sectioned-recyclerview-android/